# Parallel jenkins agents at kubernetes with kubernetes plugin

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Jenkins version 2.190.2 and Kubernetes plugin 1.19.0
I have this jenkins as master at kubernetes cluster at AWS.
This jenkins have kubernetes plugin configured and it's running ok. 
I have some pod templates and containers configured that are running.
I'm able to run declarative pipelines specifying agent and container.

My problem is that I'm unable to run jobs parallel.
When more than one job is executed at same time, first job starts, pod is created and execute stuff. The second job waits to the first jobs ends, even if use different agents.

EXAMPLE:

Pipeline 1

```
pipeline {
    agent { label "bash" }

    stages {
        stage('init') {
            steps {
                container('bash') {
                    echo 'bash'
                    sleep 300
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pipeline 2

```
pipeline {
    agent { label "bash2" }

    stages {
        stage('init') {
            steps {
                container('bash2') {
                    echo 'bash2'
                    sleep 300
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes log. I've uploaded to wetransfer -> we.tl/t-ZiSbftKZrK

I've read a lot of this problem and I've configured jenkins start with this JAVA_OPTS but problem is not solved.

```
-Dhudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.initialDelay=0 
-Dhudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.MARGIN=50 
-Dhudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.MARGIN0=0.85
```

Kubernetes plugin is configured with:

- Kubernetes cloud / Concurrency Limit = 50. I've configured without value but the problem still occurs
- Kubernetes cloud / Pod retention = never
- Pod template / Concurrency Limit without value. I've configured with 10 but the problem still occurs
- Pod template / Pod retention = Default

What configuration I'm missing or what errors i'm doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've solved my problem due to another problem.
We started to get errors at create normal pods because our kubernetes node at aws hadn't enough free ip's. Due to this error we scaled our nodes and now jenkins pipelines can be running parallel with diferents pods and containers.

Answer (score 0):

your pods are created in parallel

```
Oct 31, 2019 3:13:30 PM INFO org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher launch
Created Pod: default/bash-4wjrk
...
Oct 31, 2019 3:13:30 PM INFO org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher launch
Created Pod: default/bash2-3rxck
```

but your bash2 pod is failing with

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: jenkins-jnlp.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: But i don't understand why, because the bash2 template works fine if is launched as firsts agent. There are not problems with the templates. I think that problem is something with configuration but I don't know what can be.

Comment: then use kubectl to get the pod yaml configuration of bash and bash2 while they are running and compare them

Comment: I've compared yaml's files from bash1 at running state, bash2 at error state, bash2 at running state after bash1 has finnished. Only differences are metadata/labels/name, spec/containers/env/JENKINS_AGENT_NAME, spec/containers/env/JENKINS_NAME

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Parallel Stages](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/). Which you can find described in the Jenkins documentation for [pipeline syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel).

> Stages in Declarative Pipeline may declare a number of nested stages within a  `parallel`  block, which will be executed in parallel. Note that a stage must have one and only one of  `steps`,  `stages`, or  `parallel`. The nested stages cannot contain further  `parallel`  stages themselves, but otherwise behave the same as any other  `stage`, including a list of sequential stages within  `stages`. Any stage containing  `parallel`  cannot contain  `agent`  or  `tools`, since those are not relevant without  `steps`.
>
> In addition, you can force your  `parallel`  stages to all be aborted when one of them fails, by adding  `failFast true`  to the  `stage`  containing the  `parallel`. Another option for adding  `failfast`  is adding an option to the pipeline definition:  `parallelsAlwaysFailFast()`

An example pipeline might look like this:

```
Jenkinsfile
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Run pod') {
            parallel {
                stage('bash') {
                    agent {
                        label "init"
                    }
                    steps {
                        container('bash') {
                            echo 'bash'
                            sleep 300
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('bash2') {
                    agent {
                        label "init"
                    }
                    steps {
                        container('bash') {
                            echo 'bash'
                            sleep 300
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry crou, maybe I don't explain well my purpose. I know about parallel functions but is not what I need. I need run at the same time pipeline P1 using pod template PT1 with container C1 and Pipeline P2 using pod template PT2 with container C2.